# Java - Why won't my prime number program print the last number?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

I'm supposed to write a program for a Java Intro class that lists the prime numbers up to the number a user inputs. However, with the code I have, if the user inputs a prime number, my program won't list back that number, even though it's supposed to do so when it's prime. Could someone give me a hint as to why it's not working?

```
    int userNum=kbd.nextInt();
    if (userNum<2){
        System.out.println("Not a valid number.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("The prime numbers up to your integer are:");
    for (int num1 = 2; num1<userNum; num1++) {   
        boolean prime = true;


        for (int num2 = 2; num2 < num1; num2++) {
            if (num1 % num2 == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break; 

            }
        }

        // Prints the number if it's prime.
        if (prime) {
            System.out.print(num1 + " ");
        }
    }
```

For example, when I input "19," the program prints all prime numbers up to and including "17."
Thanks!

Comment: maybe because of this `num1<userNum`. Try changing it to `num1<=userNum`

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming, and the infamous OBOE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `num1` to take the value `userNum` as the last value to check.

Therefore, you need to replace `num1 < userNum` with `num1 <= userNum`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has a condition of `num1 < userNum`.  This means that it allows all numbers below `userNum`.  What you appear to want is all numbers below and including `userNum`, so you want `num1 <= userNum`.

The start of your loop would thus be this:

```
    for (int num1 = 2; num1 <= userNum; num1++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
num1<userNum
```

to

```
num1<=userNum
```

At the moment you stop before the two numbers are equal in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change the end condition of your for statement to num1<=userNum.